# Is it possible to call a c# function form a string?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an inv system where you can create items and give them a script to execute if a cetain condition is met. The problem is I tried to use UnityEvents but am using a Scriptable object for the items so I can't just call a runtime function. Then, I tried using an empty gameobject to hold all the item scripts and basicly if you give the name of the item's script the inv system will call a function on the item's script. But the thing is I can't just convert a string to a class that I can call the function on.

So after a long time I came up with this

```
try
{
  // scriptHolder = the gameobject where all the item scripts are
  Type type = scriptHolder.GetComponent(ondrop[i]).GetType();
  object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  type.GetMethod("onDropInv").Invoke(instance, null);
}
catch { }
```

But the thing is I need to call the function on the current instance of the script being used by unity. So I tried for the last 24h and now I give up. I just can't think of any solution or alternative.

Comment: You already do it by: type.GetMethod("onDropInv")

Comment: If you want the function to use the existing instance, pass the existing instance and stop creating new ones with `Activator`.

Comment: e.g. `instance = scriptHolder.GetComponent(ondrop[i]); type = instance.GetType();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No stop!

You are creating a new instance using the `Activator` just to call a method from it?

You already **have** an instance of the component after using `GetComponent`!

Further it is "not allowed" (you still can do it but will get a warning and unexpected behavior) to create a new instance of a `MonoBehaviour`/`Component` using `new` or the `Activator`!

---

I don't fully understand your usecase or why exactly you can not use `UnityEvent` if that's what you would rather like to do.

But your it looks like there are (at least) the following two options:

#### Use [`GameObject.SendMessage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html)

> Calls the method named `methodName` on every `MonoBehaviour` in this game object.

like e.g.

```
// scriptHolder = the gameobject where all the item scripts are
scriptHolder.SendMessage("onDropInv");
```

However, this only makes sense if the method name is actually dynamic and you don't know it beforehand.

#### Interface or base class

In your case you seem to hardcode the method name anyway so rather simply make sure that all the according components implement the interface e.g.

```
public interface IOnDropInv
{
    public void onDropInv();
}
```

like e.g.

```
public ExampleDropInv : MonoBehaviour, IOnDropInv
{
    public void onDropInv ()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello there!");
    }
}
```

and then simply do

```
scriptHolder.GetComponent<IOnDropInv>().onDropInv();
```

or they all inherit from a certain base class like

```
public abstract class BaseDropInv : MonoBehaviour
{
    public abstract void onDropInv ();
}
```

like

```
public class ExampleDropInv : BaseDropInv
{
    public override void onDropInv ()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello there!");
    }
}
```

and then do

```
scriptHolder.GetComponent<BaseDropInv>().onDropInv();
```